# C - what would be type of this variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 2D array

for ex

```
int arr[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Then what would be type of this?

```
&arr[1]
```

I thought it would be `**`(double pointer)
But when I write a function such as

```
int **get_arr()
{
    return &arr[1];
}
```

I get a warning

```
return from incompatible pointer type
```

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com). And you might want to avoid the phrase "double pointer"; it could also refer to type `double*`.

Comment: then read [this](http://stevenkobes.com/ctest.html)

Comment: @user3125280 - Is that suggestion _really_ intended to help anything?

Comment: @ryyker it definitely helped me when I first found out about multidimensional arrays - it gives several different questions very similar to OP's and includes explanations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then what would be type of this?
>
> ```
>  &arr[1]
> ```

Type of `&arr[1]` is `int (*)[3]`, i.e, it is of type *pointer to an array of 3 integers*.

> I thought it would be `**`(double pointer)

You thought wrong. `&arr[1]` is not a double pointer. As I mentioned already that, it is of type `int (*)[3]`.

Comment: Then, how should the function be declared? If it is an pointer to an array woudln't it be fine to have function return type as 'int *'? But I still get same warning as above

Comment: What do you think about the return type of function? To return an `int` you declare your function return type  `int`, for `int *` return type is `int *` for `int (*)[3]` return type of function should be what?

Comment: I will need to cast type to a pointer since you can't return an array by value?

Comment: When I told you to return array by value? (I think you mean returning a complete array).

Comment: can you return a complete array?

Comment: yeah, so I think in order to return &arr[1], I need to cast type to a pointer to int and have return type int*. is this incorrect?

Comment: First tell me, did you understand the whole thing? If not then you can ask what you did't understand.

Comment: I understood that is pointer to an array. But I am not really sure how to return an array other than in a pointer form

Comment: In fact, too many issues here. Without seeing code I can't help you because I can see, there is nothing mention about `arr` array, either it is local or global. If it is local, then you can't return a pointer to an automatic local variable.

Comment: By the way your function declaration should be look like this: `int (*get_arr(some_argument))[3];`